SCALE encoding how to get 29 bits in 4 bytes
i am trying to understand the SCALE encoding spec in the jam spec, where it says you can fit 29 bits plus a prefix.
2^21 ≤ x < 2^29, where the prefix is 0b1110, and takes up the left most 4 bits, and then there are 28 bits left for the integer.
however, i dont understand how you can get 29 bits + the prefix. I can only understand there to be 28 bits, which is 4 bits + 28 bits = 32 bits

can you explain what i am missing?

This is unused and will be removed soon from the Graypaper anyway.

It's because you only need 3 bits 0b111 as a prefix.
